# When did the Tu95 first use its armament in combat?

Tags: military, strategic-bomber, tupolev

When did the Tu95 first use its armament in combat? I know they can carry both missiles and bombs, I'm looking for the earliest date of either one being used in a combat situation.

Answer (score 4):

Last year (!), at least [per Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tupolev_Tu-95):

> On 17 November 2015, Tu-95s had their combat debut, being employed for the first time in long range airstrikes as part of the Russian military intervention in the Syrian Civil War.

This seems to have been using the Tu-95 [as a missile platform](http://m.sputniknews.com/middleeast/20151118/1030302801/russia-syria-isis-tu160-tu95-strategic-bomber.html):

> The aircraft launched a total of 34 airborne cruise missiles destroying 13 key targets...